# rm -f won't handle all arguments in bash script

Tags: bash, expansion, rm

Got a bit of a peculiar issue in bash. I want to author a script that takes a prefix of a file name and deletes all files that begin with that prefix and end in some given suffixes. To do this, I have the following line of code:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
        echo "Please provide an argument";
        exit 1
fi

# Ending dot already included in $1
rm -f $1"aux" $1"bbl" $1"blg" $1"synctex.gz" $1"log"

# But even if you call it wrong...
rm -f $1".aux" $1".bbl" $1".blg" $1".synctex.gz" $1 ".log"

exit 0
```

Unfortunately, when I call my script (which is called `cleanlatex`), as intended:

```
cmd$ cleanlatex lpa_aaai.
```

only the .aux file is deleted. Clearly `rm -f` doesn't expand its application to all arguments, which is what would've been done if I explicitly ran `rm -f lpa_aaai.aux lpa_aaai.bbl ...`. What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: To answer @Etan's question, this is what I see when I add those commands:

```
+ '[' 1 -lt 1 ']'
+ rm -v lpa_aaai.aux lpa_aaai.bbl lpa_aaai.blg lpa_aaai.synctex.gz lpa_aaai.log
removed ‘lpa_aaai.aux’
removed ‘lpa_aaai.bbl’
removed ‘lpa_aaai.blg’
removed ‘lpa_aaai.synctex.gz’
removed ‘lpa_aaai.log’
+ rm -v lpa_aaai..aux lpa_aaai..bbl lpa_aaai..blg lpa_aaai..synctex.gz lpa_aaai. .log
rm: cannot remove ‘lpa_aaai..aux’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘lpa_aaai..bbl’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘lpa_aaai..blg’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘lpa_aaai..synctex.gz’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘lpa_aaai.’: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove ‘.log’: No such file or directory
```

The second set, consisting of the `cannot remove` messages, does not concern me: I only have those removals as a fail-safe anyway. This did exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Try this: `rm -f $1{.,}{aux,bbl,blg,log,synctex.gz}`.

Comment: It has no problem on my machine, working fine with or without `.` in input.

Comment: If you are running your script from current directory, use `./` before your `.sh` file, or use `absolute path` as `/tmp/foo/myscript.sh`.

Comment: What do you see if you add `set -x` to the top of the script and add `-v` to the `rm` call?

Comment: Have a look at my edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear what your problem actually is; however, you can reduce your script to two lines of `bash`:

```
: ${1?Please provide an argument}
rm -f "$1".{aux,bbl,log,synctex.gz,log}
```

The first line has the same effect as your `if` statement, using standard POSIX parameter expansion.

The second line properly quotes `$1` and uses brace expansion to produce the sequence of file names with the desired list of suffixes. It makes the simplifying assumption that the user typed the basename of the files without the trailing period: who would type `foo.` when `foo` would suffice? You're already making the assumption that there are not files named (for instance) `foo.aux` and `foo..aux`, so you might as well make an assumption that makes for less work.

I removed `exit 0` because either `rm` succeeds and your script will exit with status 0 anyway, or `rm` fails, in which case you shouldn't be exiting with 0 status, but whatever status `rm` exits with.

Comment: Great job distilling. :) Don't forget `{.,}` to handle both the OP's `rm`'s.

Comment: This also works and is a bit more elegant than @Etan's solution. I wish I could accept two answers, yet I cannot. I shall therefore accept this for simplicity. Thanks.

Comment: @ghoti I intentionally omitted the second `rm` for clarity.

Comment: Also, in case it wasn't clear: the only reason for which I allowed the user to call the script both with *and* without a trailing '.' is because in most of the shell versions that I use, TAB-completion goes all the way to the '.', which really is exactly what it ought to do. Instead of having the user hit a backspace in order for the script to work, and because I don't feel like writing code that filters the last character in bash (it's quite messy in my experience), I opted to just make two different `rm` calls. It's not a big deal when just deleting 5 files.